# How to do pow_mod256?

Tags: solidity, vyper, math, pow

Vyper has the built in function [a ** b % (2 ** 256)](https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/v0.2.15/built-in-functions.html#pow_mod256). Is there any way to make the same calculation in Solidity?

Answer (score 1):

you can do the same calculation " a ** b % (2 ** 256) " in Solidity using the power function (**) for exponentiation and the modulo operator (%) for the remainder after division. But Solidity does not support arbitrary precision arithmetic, so the result of the exponentiation must fit within the range of the uint256 data type.

Here is how you could write this in Solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract PowerAndModulo {
    function calculate(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        require(a <= type(uint256).max / b, "Exponentiation overflow");
        
        uint256 result = a ** b;
        result %= type(uint256).max +  1; // Since  2 **  256 wraps around to zero
        return result;
    }
}
```

The calculate function takes two uint256 parameters, a and b.

The require statement checks for potential overflow during the exponentiation.
If a is too large, the result would exceed the maximum value that can be held by a uint256, causing an overflow error.

The result is calculated using the power function (a ** b).

The result is then reduced modulo (2 ** 256) using the %= operator.
Note that since 2 ** 256 is larger than the maximum value that can be represented by a uint256, it wraps around to zero.

Therefore, the line result %= type(uint256).max + 1; is used to account for this wrapping behavior.

The function returns the final result of the calculation.

Comment: This line doesn't make sense `result %= type(uint256).max + 1`. The variable `result` is already a `uint256`. Calculating `result %= 2**256` should do nothing.

Comment: you are correct thanks for pointing it out, what would you suggest?

Comment: I suspect that vyper is doing something more interesting. Perhaps it is using some mathematical trick or a precompiled contract.

Answer (score 0):

Although Solidity has both exponentiation and modulo operators, simply doing `a ** b % (2 ** 256)` will revert when `a ** b` is greater than `2 ** 256` due to [integer overflow protection](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html) in Solidity version `>=0.8`.

You can either:

- Use an [`unchecked { ... }`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#checked-or-unchecked-arithmetic) block to disable integer overflow protection.
- Use [inline assembly](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/assembly.html) to directly call the [`EXP` opcode (`0A`)](https://www.evm.codes/#0a?fork=shanghai).
- Use a version of Solidity `<0.8`.

Note that in all three of these solutions, the `% (2 ** 256)` is no longer needed because the modulo is already implied by the integer overflow.

Here are Solidity implementations of the [example function](https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/stable/built-in-functions.html#pow_mod256) from the Vyper documentation using all three solutions below:

### Use an `unchecked { ... }` block

```
function foo(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
    unchecked {
        return a ** b;
    }
}
```

### Use inline assembly to call `EXP` directly

```
function foo(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 ret;
    assembly {
        ret := exp(a, b)
    }
    return ret;
}
```

### Use a version of Solidity `<0.8`

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.6; // IMPORTANT: must be <0.8

// ...

function foo(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
    return a ** b;
}
```